# Who brings down that Nachshon's offering did not come from his tribe?

Tags: princes-of-tribes

Who brings down that Nachshon's princely offering did not come from his tribe?

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the [Sifri, Nasso 48](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.48.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which writes that it came from his personal wealth and not from his tribe:

> ויהי המקריב ביום הראשון שאין ת"ל ראשון אלא ראשון לכל ימות השנה. נחשון בן עמינדב למטה יהודה יחסו הכתוב על שם שבטו. או שגבה משבטו והביא, **ת"ל זה קרבן נחשון בן עמינדב משלו הביא ולא שגבה משבטו והביא**. הא מה ת"ל נחשון בן עמינדב למטה יהודה יחסו הכתוב על שם שבטו
>
> (Bamidbar 7:12) "And the one who presented his offering on the first day": What is the intent of this? "first" of all the days of the year (i.e., the first of Nissan). "Nachshon ben Aminadav of the tribe of Judah": Is the intent of this attribution to link him with his tribe or to indicate that he obtained (the offering) from his tribe and brought it? It is, therefore, written (Ibid. 17) **"This is the offering of Nachshon ben Aminadav" — his personal offering and not his tribe's.** What, then, is the intent of Nachshon ben Aminadav of the tribe of Judah"? To link him with his tribe.